# If $\partial_i f_j(\overline x)=\partial_j f_i(\overline x)$, then $f=\nabla u$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, convex set such that $\overline 0\in\Omega$. Let $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function. Also, $\partial_i f_j(\overline x)=\partial_j f_i(\overline x)$ for all $i,j$. I'm trying to show that there exists a differentiable function $u\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla u(\overline x)=f(\overline x)$ for all $\overline x\in\Omega$.

**My attempt:**

Given that $\Omega$ is convex, we can connect an arbitrary point $\overline x\in\Omega$ to the origin with a line, i.e. $t\overline x\in\Omega$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Let then

$$u(\overline x)=\int_0^1 f(t\overline x)\cdot\overline x\, dt$$

Expanding the dot product, we have that

$$u(\overline x)=\sum_{\ell=1}^n x_\ell \int_0^1 f_\ell (t\overline x) \, dt$$

Now, let $\overline e\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|\overline e\|=1$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{u(\overline x+h\overline e)-u(\overline x)}{h} &=\frac{1}{h} \sum_\ell \left[(x_\ell+h e_\ell)\int_0^1 f_\ell(t(\overline x+h\overline e)) \, dt-x_\ell \int_0^1 f_\ell (t\overline x) \, dt\right] \\
&=\sum_\ell \left[x_\ell \int_0^1 \frac{f_\ell(t(\overline x+h\overline e))-f_\ell(t\overline x)}{h} \, dt +e_\ell\int_0^1 f_\ell(t(\overline x+h\overline e)) \, dt \right].
\end{align*}
$$

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $\xi_\ell,\xi_\ell'\in[0,1]$ such that

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{f_\ell(t(\overline x+h\overline e))-f_\ell(t\overline x)}{h} \, dt=\frac{f_\ell(\xi_\ell(\overline x+h\overline e))-f_\ell(\xi_\ell\overline x)}{h} $$

and

$$ \int_0^1 f_\ell(t(\overline x+h\overline e)) \, dt=f_\ell(\xi_\ell'(\overline x+h\overline e)). $$

Letting $h\to 0$, we get that

$$ \partial_{\overline e}u(\overline x)=\sum_\ell \left[x_\ell \partial_{\overline e} f_\ell(\xi_\ell\overline x)+e_\ell f_\ell(\xi_\ell'\overline x) \right].$$

Therefore, when $\overline e=\overline e_i$ is one of the standard basis vectors, we have

$$ \partial_i u(\overline x) =\sum_\ell x_\ell\partial_i(\xi_\ell\overline x)+f_i(\xi_i'\overline x).$$

This is where I get stuck. It should be that $\partial_i u(\overline x)=f_i(\overline x)$, but how do I get that? Playing around with a few concrete examples, it does work out if you choose the correct values for $\xi$, but how can I do that in general? Or is that even possible, is this even in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

This is basically a generalization of the fact that in $\mathbb{R}^3$, if $\nabla\times f=\overline 0$, then by Stokes' theorem (for a suitable set $\Omega$ like here) the vector field $f$ is conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard trick is to use the chain rule twice.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(\bar x)
    &= \int_0^1 \sum_{\ell}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\left(f_\ell(t \bar x) x_\ell\right) \,dt
    \\&= \int_0^1 \sum_{\ell}\left(\frac{\partial f_\ell}{\partial x_i}(t \bar x) tx_\ell + f_\ell(t\bar x)\frac{\partial x_\ell}{\partial x_i}\right) \,dt
    \\&= \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{\ell}\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_\ell}(t \bar x) tx_\ell + f_i(t\bar x)\right) \,dt
    \\&= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}\left(f_i(t\bar x)t\right) \,dt
    \\&= \left.\mathstrut f_i(t\bar x)t\right|^{t=1}_{t=0} =f_i(\bar x)
\end{align*}